# non-deterministic number of CASE WHEN clause in JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, case, jooq

I want to generate a `CASE WHEN` sub query like this:

```
CASE DEVICE.ID WHEN 12  THEN 'some-string-1'
               WHEN 34  THEN 'some-string-2'
END
```

But number of `WHEN` clauses are non-deterministic and will be available at run time. I have a `Map<Integer, String>` which the key will be the `WHEN` condition and the corresponding value is the `THEN` part. What I need is something like this:

```
CaseValueStep<Integer> caseValueStep = DSL.decode().value(DEVICE.ID);
for (Integer deviceId : devices.keySet()) {
    caseValueStep = caseValueStep.when(deviceId, devices.get(deviceId));
}
```

But the problem is after the first `when()` the result become `CaseWhenStep`. Is there is any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular use-case, yes, there is a solution through [`DSL.decode()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#decode-T-T-Z-java.lang.Object...-):

```
DSL.decode(DEVICE.ID, 12, "some-string-1", 34, "some-string-2", ...);
```

Note the varargs argument. It's still a bit clumsy, as the first case has to be passed outside of the varargs argument. If you're using Oracle, this will translate to the actual `DECODE()` function. If you're using any other database, that'll translate to the `CASE` expression you've had in mind.

For more general use-cases, [#3691](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3691) has been implemented for jOOQ 3.8 to allow for the following:

```
Map<Integer, String) map = ...
DSL.choose(DEVICE.ID).mapValues(map);
```